# Raspberry Pi3 Jessie will not reconnect after ethernet cable re-plugged

Tags: networking, raspbian-jessie, ethernet, connection

My Pi3 running Jessie loses connectivity after unplugging and plugging back the ethernet cable. It's literally driving me crazy. Hope you could shed some light here.

Wifi is disabled in /boot/config and raspi-blacklist.

```
/etc/network/interfaces is as follows:

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet manual


#allow-hotplug wlan0
#iface wlan0 inet dhcp
#    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

#allow-hotplug wlan1
#iface wlan1 inet manual
#    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Thank you

Comment: Does it work if you do an `ifup eth0` ?

Comment: Even though you have commented it out, the file contains a reference to `dhcp` which is invalid. This may be related to your problem. See [How to set up networking/WiFi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem that the network would not work after restarting the switch attached.

The problem was solved by

```
ifconfig eth0 down && ifconfig eth0 up
```

As my machine is headless, I set up a script to bother with keeping the connection alive.

Here is a pseudo code example

```
if (ping 192.168.0.1 doesn't work) then ifconfig eth0 down && ifconfig eth0 up && sleep 120 #to reduce the load implied by the script and give the system a chance to get its DHCP set up.
```

end if